# CodeIgniter: Website displays database error when accessed through Google

Tags: database, codeigniter, search

When I click on the website through Google, the page displays a database error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'referrer_keywords' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `st_referrer` (`referrer_type`, `referrer_url`,
>   `referrer_keywords`, `referrer_time`) VALUES ('Search Engine',
>   'www.google.com.au', NULL, 1426669760)
>
> Filename: libraries/Analytics.php
>
> Line Number: 186

When I visit the page directly however (either via entering URL or navigating to it) it loads perfectly fine.

For some reason the website is also being poorly ranked and indexed. The **homepage** doesn't appear in Google's results at all. Only two somewhat random pages do, and these pages show on the second page of Google's results, even though I use exact keywords which match the site's name. Both of these pages produce identical errors when clicked.

Comment: Google doesn't pass any referrer keywords. Can you just allow null in that table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From error example is ovious that column refferer_keywords is set with NOT NULL attribute. If you need to pass NULL field value, change column attribute. It could solve problem.